# Safari unexpectedly quit - my first ~20 tabs are gone

Tags: macos, safari, monterey

Safari just quit on me out of nowhere when I wasn't looking.

When I opened Safari again, apart from my first 4 pinned tabs, the next few tabs (in the region of 10-20 of them) are not there any more. My last (rightmost) 11 tabs are all still there in the same state.

History > Recently Closed doesn't list any of those tabs, and History > Reopen All Windows from Last Session and History > Reopen Last Closed Window just reopened the same window I was already looking at (with only my first 4 pinned tabs and last 11 of the rest).

Show tab overview and searching for the names of the tabs that used to exist also doesn't bring them up.

Where did my middle tabs go? How might I be able to get them back?